# Terminating task in celery 3.1.18

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have a django app with some celery tasks, I'm staring worker with

```
celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10
```

I run task with `task.deploy()`, but when I try to terminate task with `celery.task.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)`

I'm getting

```
[2015-07-27 14:27:04,736: ERROR/MainProcess] Task task[80e06e87-f254-4c0b-bea5-5c21540777ab] raised unexpected: Terminated(15,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blake/projects/venv/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1674, in _set_terminated
    raise Terminated(-(signum or 0))
Terminated: 15
```

I was looking for post about this error, but I have only found 3 years old post which didn't help me at all.

I'm using

```
celery==3.1.18
kombu==3.0.25
billiard==3.3.0.20
```

So how do I successfully terminate an already running task?

EDIT: Task is however being terminated but code stops executing because of exception and somehow except is not catching Exception

```
try:
    revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
except Terminated:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating task you need to specify the Exception which will be thrown inside task

```
from billiard.exceptions import Terminated

@task(throws=(Terminated,))
def task():
   ...
```

Comment: I'm running into an identical issue running on celery 3.1.25. The exception is thrown from the MainProcess, so I'm not sure how raising an exception from the worker can resolve this issue?